# Unable to log in using Safari or Chrome – SSL Certificate Issues

Tags: support, login, ssl

OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 / Chrome 33.0... / Safari 7.0.2

I am unable to log in to StackOverflow using Chrome or Safari. Clicking the "log in" link displays a login page UN-styled by CSS and where the "Login" button does not respond to mouse clicks. I am, however able to log in using FireFox, which I am using to post this question.

In Chrome I tried disabling all Extensions, but the faulty page display persisted.

Any thoughts?

**Edit with Additional Information:**

Opening the Developer Consoles while on the Login page [https://stackoverflow.com/users/login] in both Chrome and Safari, I am seeing *certificate issues* for cdn.sstatic.net resources:

- `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` (in Chrome)
- `Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be...` (in Safari)

While I am able to reach cdn.sstatic.net in all browsers via http, I am blocked in Safari/Chrome when I try to access it via https:

- `The site's security certificate is not trusted!` and
- `Safari can't verify the identify of the website "cdn.sstatic.net"`

Safari show me that the certificate ("ssl4121.cloudflare.com") is for cloudflare.com whereas the link is for sstatic.net, thus throwing the error.

**My Interim Solution**

- Visit https://cdn.sstatic.net in Safari/Chrome
- Click "Proceed anyway" in Chrome
- Click "Show Certificate" in Safari, then select "Always Trust" in the "Trust: When using this certificate" dropdown.

Now, visiting the login page correctly displays the correct CSS and allows me to Log In (finally).

Feels like a bit of a hack, but it worked.

**Certificate: Unknown Authority**

I removed the certificate ("ssl4121.cloudflare.com") from my Keychain in Keychain Access in order to re-test this issue. The results were the same, with an unstyled and unusable Login page.

After I re-imported the certificate into Keychain Access, the message "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority" is displayed in red near the top. When I mark it again as "Trusted", that message disappears.

Comment: Apparently, the static domain is blocked.

Comment: Weird, my Safari (and other browsers, all latest version, on latest OS X) have no trouble with that certificate. It defines a Subject Alternative Name extension, [which includes \*.sstatic.net](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b0GKX.png). Your Mavericks seems up to date as well. As for *"Safari show me that the certificate ("ssl4121.cloudflare.com") is for cloudflare.com whereas the link is for sstatic.net, thus throwing the error"*: is it really saying that the different name is the cause? Or is that your own conclusion and do we need to investigate other options (such as missing root certificates)?

Comment: That was my own, perhaps simplistic, conclusion.

Comment: (In case you don't: see [Replying in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply).)

Comment: Then can you double-click the HTTPS icon in the browser's address bar for https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css, and scroll to see if there's any error message? See also the certificate in my Safari: [Part 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yohqt.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cczy.png), [3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZsom.png), [4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RFOI6.png).

Comment: Also, click the "parent" certificates in that dialog. And make sure your clock (date, year) is correct?

Comment: Ah, I missed your earlier edit of the question.  Which issuer is not trusted? The GlobalSign Root CA, or the intermediate GlobalSign Organization Validation? And did you install all Mavericks updates?

Comment: @Arjan Ah, it's GlobalSign Root CA that's not trusted. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/DNeUCYh.png). And yes, I've installed all Mavericks updates and my clock is correct.

Comment: @Arjan First, I removed the trusted certificate from Keychain. Then, from Chrome, here are the messages and certificate information I got by double clicking the HTTPS icon for "all.css": [1](http://i.imgur.com/gLVTFrr.png) [2](http://i.imgur.com/UKXjvdR.png) [3](http://i.imgur.com/7AxVvUhttp://i.png) [4](http://i.imgur.com/cX4uirj.png) [5](http://i.imgur.com/a2cie8o.png) [6](http://i.imgur.com/wEkPL1h.png)

Comment: Just to be sure: you only removed the trusted Cloudfare certificate, right? I find it odd that the error for GlobalSign says (emphasis mine): *This certificate **is marked** as not not trusted for all users.* I wonder if that means it has somehow been explicitly marked as such. Guess you'll never find out. To compare: I've got [quite a few GlobalSign certificates](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LVGkh.png) in Keychain. In case you want to compare hashes before you maker the root as trusted: my [part 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bpc6J.png) and [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT85n.png).

Comment: Ah, Keychain's preferences shows an option in General: *"Reset My Default Keychain - Reverts to factory defaults and creates a new empty "login" keychain. Your current default keychain will be moved aside, but not deleted."* Also, in Certificates, I have - "Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)" and "Certificate Revocation List (CRL)" both set to "Best attempt", and "Priority" to "OCSP". (I've not changed anything there, I think.)

Comment: (Hmmm, one "not" too many in my previous comment, but too late to edit. Just for SEO: *This certificate is marked as not trusted for all users*.)

Comment: @Arjan Yes, I only removed the CloudFlare certificate. And my Keychain settings are the same as yours.

Comment: @Arjan I have several GlobalSign certificates, and all but two are marked as untrusted. Also, they seem to be untrusted only on my laptop, and not on my office desktop. I have a very vague memory of some GlobalSign certificates being suspect a couple years ago, so they may have all been explicitly marked as untrusted then, without understanding all the consequences. I guess now I have to find a way to back out of that situation. I'll try comparing my hashes to yours. And perhaps see if starting over with a new keychain is feasible.

Comment: For a quick hash compare: in Keychain Access you can drag the certificate icon to export it. (Or use menu File, Export.) If stored on the desktop, running `md5 ~/Desktop/"GlobalSign Root CA.cer"` in Terminal gets me `3e455215095192e1b75d379fb187298a`. (The same as shown in the screenshots.)

Comment: @Arjan Perfect. Done, and solved. Thanks so much.

Comment: Located some background on why I may have marked the GlobalSign certificates untrusted [here](http://www.informationweek.com/attacks/globalsign-says-no-new-certificates-pending-investigation/d/d-id/1099990).

Comment: @Albioner if you have removed the certificate issuer, then this sounds self-inflicted...

Comment: @MarcGravell Correct. Though, not without cause. There was in fact a GlobalSign [breach](http://www.informationweek.com/attacks/globalsign-says-no-new-certificates-pending-investigation/d/d-id/1099990) in 2011, and recommendations were made, valid or not, to not trust GS certificates at the time. This is the likely source of the problem. It would be nice to provide a concise Answer to this question, though, as much of a self-inflicted edge case as it seems to be. While "Apparently, the static domain is blocked." was correct, the actual solution was more specific. Anyway...

Comment: @Albioner well, the question is not closed (any more); the floor is yours if you wish to add the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL/TLS security works by certificate chains. On any domain we support TLS on, we serve a certificate. That certificate was issued by someone - in the case of cdn.sstatic.net it was issues by [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/). For the sites directly it's currently [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com/) (Stack Exchange vs. CloudFlare getting the cert). That certificate tells who issued the cert, whether it be a certificate authority or an intermediate.

That's how trust works, you trust the certificates all the way up the chain *until you get to one you know and trust*.  Your browser or machine has a list of CAs that you trust, so when a certificate chain connects to those, you know you've established a chain of trust, and therefore trust our certificate.

If you mark one of those CAs as untrusted ***you no longer trust us*** and the browser appropriately blocks the content, since it's from an untrusted source.  What happens if you do that? **Things will break**, which is what happened here.

Bottom Line: **Don't do that**

Be aware that marking a well known certificate authority as untrusted will have consequences across the internet.

Comment: Right. There was in fact a GlobalSign [breach](http://www.informationweek.com/attacks/globalsign-says-no-new-certificates-pending-investigation/d/d-id/1099990) in 2011, and recommendations were made, valid or not, to _not trust GS certificates_ at the time. This is the likely source of the problem. Another learning experience. Thanks for all the help.